# sqldeveloper - java.nio.BufferUnderflowException

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

after starting sqldeveloper on windows 10 and then trying to connect to an 12c Database we receive the following java error stacktrace.

This Problem occurs, when trying sqldeveloper version 4.2 or 17.2

Any Ideas ?

Best
hg

```
java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.get(HeapByteBuffer.java:151)
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.get(ByteBuffer.java:715)
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOAcceptPacket.readPayloadBuffer(NIOAcceptPacket.java:167)
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readNIOPacket(NIOPacket.java:282)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolNIO.java:118)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:317)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1438)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:518)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:688)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:691)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.db.adapter.AbstractConnectionCreator.getConnection(AbstractConnectionCreator.java:229)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.standalone.connection.RaptorConnectionCreator.getConnectionImpl(RaptorConnectionCreator.java:392)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.standalone.connection.RaptorConnectionCreator.getConnection(RaptorConnectionCreator.java:118)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.dialogs.conn.ConnectionPrompt.promptForPassword(ConnectionPrompt.java:67)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.db.adapter.DatabaseProviderHelper$PasswordPrompter.promptForPassword(DatabaseProviderHelper.java:422)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.db.DBConnAddin$2.promptForPassword(DBConnAddin.java:98)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.db.adapter.DatabaseProvider.getConnection(DatabaseProvider.java:434)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.db.adapter.DatabaseProvider.getConnection(DatabaseProvider.java:365)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.db.adapter.CAConnectionCreator.createConnectionImpl(CAConnectionCreator.java:68)
    at oracle.javatools.db.DatabaseFactory.createConnection(DatabaseFactory.java:838)
    at oracle.javatools.db.DatabaseFactory.createDatabase(DatabaseFactory.java:282)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.db.DatabaseConnections.getDatabase(DatabaseConnections.java:837)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.utils.Connections$ConnectionInfo.getDatabase(Connections.java:281)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.utils.Connections.getConnection(Connections.java:1201)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.utils.Connections.getConnection(Connections.java:1187)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.db.DatabaseConnection.openConnectionImpl(DatabaseConnection.java:146)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.db.DatabaseConnection.openConnectionImpl(DatabaseConnection.java:41)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.db.BaseConnectionNode.getConnection(BaseConnectionNode.java:46)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.db.impl.DatabaseTreeNode.getObjectFactory(DatabaseTreeNode.java:90)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.db.impl.DatabaseTreeNode$LoadTask.doWork(DatabaseTreeNode.java:145)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.db.impl.DatabaseTreeNode$LoadTask.doWork(DatabaseTreeNode.java:119)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTask.call(RaptorTask.java:193)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTaskManager$RaptorFutureTask.run(RaptorTaskManager.java:629)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Just a question - is it about 12.2. or 12.1. version of Oracle DB? I think I saw somewhere, that the latest jdbc is meant for 12.1, but not sure, might be due to this issue. If it's not the case, then its something about the Sql Developer. try downloading it again and check the cksums of what you downloaded, reinstall and if all else fails, try a lower version. I had numerous connection issues with sqlDev 4.2. on Windows 10 and it basically boils down to a problem related to Windows 10 actually.

Comment: may be current version might have some bug, try downloading the previous version

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic). **-** You might want to create an account at [oracle website](https://login.oracle.com/mysso/signon.jsp) and ask your question in the [SQL-Developer Community](https://community.oracle.com/community/database/developer-tools/sql_developer)

Answer (score 2):

You can disable Nio with steps below:

1. Go to **[SQLDeveloper_home]**\sqldeveloper\bin folder and backup sqldeveloper.conf file.
2. Edit sqldeveloper.conf and add at the end of the file the following line:

   **AddVMOption -Doracle.jdbc.javaNetNio=false**
3. Save the file and then restart the SQLDeveloeper.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to upgrade the Oracle JDBC driver in your sqldeveloper install. Locate ojdbc8.jar and replace it with the latest one which can be downloaded from OTN. Then restart JDev and the problem should go away.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with SQL Developer 18. I downgraded the Oracle driver to the one supplied with Oracle 12.1 ([ojdbc7.jar](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/default-2280470.html)). I can now connect just fine.